# I have a error while creating Maven project for Alfresco in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'share'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.10 from http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of sonatype-public has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.10 from/to sonatype-public (http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public): oss.sonatype.org

Comment: Please tell us what you wanted to do and what you've already tried to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check your internet connection whether is it proxy connection or direct connection. if your connection through proxy then

Go to Eclipse Window > Preferences > Network Connections and set there proxy entries like your IP address, Port, Localhost...

Hope it helps......